# create table and tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this code in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    var reservations = [{
        "HotelId": "01",
        "HotelName": "ספא וילג' הוטל",
        "ReservNum": "0166772",
        "Guest Name": "רוני לוי",
        "Room": "323",
        "Type": "SUIT",
        "Rooms": "1",
        "Board": "HBDB",
        "Status": "CN",
        "Pax": "2,0,0,0",
        "Arrival": "07/08/12",
        "Departure": "12/08/12",
        "AgentDesc": "FIT",
        "AgentCode": "FIT",
        "Group": null,
        "Balance": "0",
        "Requests": "",
        "Remarks": "1424 ש ח חצי פנסיון+2טיפולים",
        "Fit/Group": "FIT",
        "ReturnGuestName": "רוני לוי",
        "StatusColor": "LightGreen"
    },
{
    "HotelId": "01",
    "HotelName": "ספא וילג' הוטל",
    "ReservNum": "0166778",
    "Guest Name": "ולדה קאטם",
    "Room": "028",
    "Type": "LOCK",
    "Rooms": "1",
    "Board": "BLUE",
    "Status": "IH",
    "Pax": "2,0,0,0",
    "Arrival": "07/08/12",
    "Departure": "07/08/12",
    "AgentDesc": "מנויים חמת גדר",
    "AgentCode": "001",
    "Group": null,
    "Balance": "0",
    "Requests": "",
    "Remarks": "761 ש ח כ+ט+א*2",
    "Fit/Group": "FIT",
    "ReturnGuestName": "",
    "StatusColor": "LightCoral"
}];

var tbody = $('#reservations tbody');
var props = ["ReservNum", "Guest Name", "Status", "Arrival", "Departure", "Type"];
$.each(reservations, function (i, reservation) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(props, function (i, prop) 
    {
        if (reservation[prop] == "CN") 
        {
            $('<td class="CN">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
        }
        else if (reservation[prop] == "IH")
        {
            $('<td class="IH">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
        }
        else 
        {
            $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
        }
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
});
});
```

In the loop I have this line:

```
 $('<td class="CN">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

This create me in the html: `<td class="CN"> CN </td>`

I want to change it, because I want to make this line in html:
`<td><img class="CN"> CN </td>`

I have try to do:

```
$('<td><img class="CN">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

But it don't do the job.

Do someone know what I need to change in the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<td><img class="CN" />'+reservation[prop]+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this line:

```
$('<td class="CN">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

With this:

```
 $('<td><img class="CN">').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

Comment: As I wrote, I had done it but it's don't do the job.
This only create me a regular html line:
<td>CN</td>

Answer (score 0):

Add tags you want in the `html` function :

```
$('<td class="CN">').removeClass('CN').html('<img class="CN">'+reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

But this HTML code is not valid, `img` tag is used to define image.

Comment: I know, I want to add image and this is the reason I want img tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a jsfiddle?
Try this instead

```
$('<td><img class="CN">').append(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('td.CN').append('<img class="CN"');
$('td.CN').append.html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);
```